# What is the N001VEP symbology in the Su-27SM?

Tags: radar, su-27

I saw on Wikipedia that the N001VEP radar in the Su-27SM can track 10 targets at a time and engage 4 of them at a time.

So, what is the symbology of the N001VEP in the Su-27SM that allows it to do this? Because the base Su-27 has the radar symbology on the HUD, and it doesn't seem like this would be possible with radar symbology on the HUD.

Also, why can't they conceivably engage 10 targets at a time if they had missiles?

Comment: The question is a bit muddled…. How does symbology either “allow” or inhibit the number of targets being tracked?  Whether you choose “X” or “O” for the targets, or choose to display them on the HUD or main screen, isn’t this just a user interface decision made during software development?

Comment: "*why can't they conceivably engage 10 targets*": That's not a matter of interface, but of switching the radar from the pulse-Doppler mode used in tracking to the more resource-demanding CW mode required for [missile homing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-active_radar_homing).